# Show ProgressDialog ONLY when process is long

Tags: android, progressdialog

I'm wondering how do you show `ProgressDialog` only in that case when process takes long time?

In my case program works with internet and if phone is connected via WiFi so there's no need in progressDialogs since it would flash for half a sec. And vise versa when internet is slow its needed to show them.

How can I do such:

```
if (process takes > 1 sec) -> ProgressDialog.show(...)
```

Comment: Why do you want to show progress only for long process. It is not bad to display dialog everytime

Comment: I think its a mess on screen when it flashes for 0.1 sec on screen. You can't even read the message there in Dialog

Comment: You are right but it is UX issue, you can for example lock button or change it to progress, it is better solution.

Comment: show it in both cases. Even though is really quick is always good to give  a feedback to the user that something is changing/updating. On the other hand I agree with you for the fact that the `ProgressDialog` is kind of ugly. On solution could be a transparent layout with a progress spinner, placed on the bottom of the screen, and you can hide and show this layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you are running your process. In the case of AsyncTask just start a timer when you start the async task. Then in your doInBackground you can query for the elapsed time and call publishProgress if the time is greater then a few seconds. Then in onProgressUpdate publish your dialog.

If your not using async task you'll have to adjust for whatever method your following. Generally capture the start time, poll to query the current time, when you surpass your time threshold display progress dialog.

```
 private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<FOO, FOO, FOO> {
 protected Long doInBackground(FOO... foo) {
     //Do normal operation
     long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     boolean showDialog = false;
     if (elapsedTime - startTime > TIME_THRESHOLD) {
        showDialog = true;
        publishProgress(0);
     }

     while( !showDialog ) {
        elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (elapsedTime - startTime > TIME_THRESHOLD) {
          showDialog = true;
          publishProgress(0);
        }
     }
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     //Show dialog
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     //Do whatever
 }
}
startTime = system.currentTimeMillis();
new MyTask().execute();
```

This is a pretty rough implementations, the time checking can be improved but should give a rough idea of how to make it work. startTime in this case would be a class variable in your containing class.

Comment: I'm working with AsyncTasks. Please post the example of usage of that timer.